# aligning tables left and right for responsive html emails - Outlook 2010 Issue

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Im having an issue with a 'nav' area of an email im coding. it works fine in all browsers and works responsively, but does this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmou0.jpg) when opened in outlook.

the code for the block is below.

any ideas how i can make it sit next to the left element?

```
<layout label='Nav'>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="580" class="deviceWidth" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;">
    <tr>
    <td>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="50%" class="deviceWidth" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr bgcolor="#9cacbc"><td class="borderBottom" width="50%" style="font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; margin-top:0; padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
    <singleline><a href="#" title="Brochures" style="color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration:none;"><font color="#ffffff">Brochures</font></a></singleline>
</td>
<td class="noBorder borderBottom" width="50%" style="font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; margin-top:0; padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px;border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
        <singleline><a href="#" title="Specials" style="color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration:none;"><font color="#ffffff">Specials</font></a></singleline>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" width="50%" class="deviceWidth" style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr bgcolor="#9cacbc"><td width="50%" style="font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; margin-top:0; padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
        <singleline><a href="#" title="Destinations" style="color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration:none;"><font color="#ffffff">Destinations</font></a></singleline>
</td>
<td width="50%" style="font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff !important; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: top; margin-top:0; padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px;">
        <singleline><a href="#" title="Contact us" style="color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration:none;"><font color="#ffffff">Contact us</font></a></singleline>

        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</td></tr>
</table>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: VML
Method 2: use cells(td) rather than floating tables.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word (not IE) for rendering HTML markup. Try to open your page in Word to make sure that it works correctly. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope you will find this information helpful.